# Preserve, Protect, and Defend

Tags: terminology

What is the difference between *preserve*, *protect*, and *defend* in the following sentence, which is the Oath of office of the President of the United States:

> "I do solemnly swear (or affirm) that I will faithfully execute the Office of President of the United States, and will to the best of my Ability, preserve, protect and defend the Constitution of the United States."

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: look up preserve, protect, and defend, and determine the differences